# Writing a hashCode method for a class in Scala 3

Tags: scala

I am working through *Scala for the Impatient (3rd) Edition* by Horstmann.  I'm scratching my head over this assignment.

*Write a class Circle with a center and a radius.  Add equals and hashCode methods.  Activate multiversal equality.*

I'm not sure how to implement the hashCode method.  This is what I came up with.

```
package circle:
    import scala.language.strictEquality

    class Circle(val radius: Double, val x: Double, val y: Double):
        def centerPoint = (x, y)
        final override def equals(other: Any) =
            other match
                case a: Circle => radius == a.radius && centerPoint == a.centerPoint
        override def hashCode(): Int = radius.hashCode() + x.hashCode() + y.hashCode()
```

I'm pretty sure that's wrong though.

```
  val circle1 = Circle(2.0, 0, 0)
  print(s"Circle center: ${circle1.centerPoint}\n")
  print(s"Circle radius is: ${circle1.radius}\n")
  print(s"circle1 hashCode: ${circle1.hashCode()}\n")
  val circle2 = Circle(2.0, 0, 0)
  print(s"Is circle1 equal to circle2? ${circle1 == circle2}\n")
  print(s"circle2 hashCode: ${circle2.hashCode()}\n")
```

Yields

```
Circle center: (0.0,0.0)
Circle radius is: 2.0
circle1 hashCode: 1073741824
Is circle1 equal to circle2? true
circle2 hashCode: 1073741824
```

If memory serves, hashes are supposed to be unique, so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.  Should I be using *hashCode*?  I have noticed in several posts that users are using *##*, which is supposed to be memory safe.

Comment: You'll very rarely have to write `equals`/`hashcode` methods in Scala (and Java as well actually). You either use Scala's `case class`, Java's `record` or a library to do it (isn't it even part of the JDK now actually?!).

Comment: Hashes are NOT supposed to be unique - they are supposed to be equal if `equals` should be true BUT they might be equal for non equal values. The intent is that they should be a cheap heuristic to tell if it's worth to perform potentially expensive equality check. For hash-bases collections they should also have kinda uniform value distribution. But by definition they cannot be unique as they map potentially infinite set of values into finite set of integers.

Comment: And since circle1 and circle2 in your example should be equal (they are records constructed with the same values...), by the contract they have to have equal hashCodes.